# How to fill empty data with zeros?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, set-difference

After going through some previous answers I found that I could use this code to fill missing values of df1[0] which range from 340 to 515,

```
with open('contactasortedtest.dat', 'r') as f:
    text = [line.split() for line in f]
def replace_missing(df1 , Ids ):
        missing = np.setdiff1d(Ids,df1[1])
        print(missing)
        if len(missing) > 0 :
            missing_df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.zeros( (len(missing) , 4 )))
            missing_df[1] = missing
            missing_df[2].replace(0 , df1[2].iloc[1] , inplace = True)
            df1 = pd.concat([df1 , missing_df])
        return df1
Ids = (np.arange(340.0,515.0))
final_df = df1.groupby(df1[2],as_index=True).apply(replace_missing ,Ids).reset_index(drop = True)
final_df
```

Through troubleshooting I found that `missing = np.setdiff1d(Ids,df1[1])` does not perform. Rather return the whole array. I found many answers on this, but I couldn't work it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Sample data I used,

```
12 340.0 1.0 0.0
 2 491.0 1.0 35.8
13 492.0 1.0 81.4
 4 493.0 1.0 0.0
 7 495.0 1.0 0.2
 0 496.0 1.0 90.3
11 509.0 1.0 2.3
 6 513.0 1.0 4.3
 8 515.0 1.0 0.1
```

Thank you !

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "empty data". `fillna` is already mentioned, but given the use of `np.arange(340.0,515.0)`, I suspect you somehow want to extend your dataframe, with rows filling in sequential integer values (even if the type is float) in the second column. But in that case, it is unclear what the values in the other columns should be.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `df['x'].fillna(0)` to fill non zeros in a column